# htaccess - Divert all expect some traffic to a subdirectory without redirecting(modifying url)

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I know how to redirect using htaccess. What I want to do is, if one tries to access `/file.php` then to serve the file from a sub-directory, i.e. `/subdirectory/file.php` without actually modifying the url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^file\.php$ /subdirectory/file.php [L]
```

Without the `R` flag, the rewrite engine won't flag the request as needed an external redirect (and thus changing the URL in the browser's location bar). It will serve the contents of `/subdirectory/file.php` internally on the server without the browser knowing.

---

This seems like something entirely different from what you asked:

> I am using RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9.]*)$ /subdirectory/$1 [L] . How to handle slashes(/) in this regex? I tried with escaping and not-escaping it but gave Error 500 in both case

You're causing a loop, you need:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdirectory/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdirectory/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Great. What if I want divert all, expect for one file? What will be the regex for that?

Comment: @emotionull instead of `^file\.php$`, you'd have `!^file\.php$`

Comment: Just discovered it doesn't work if its a `HTTPS` request for sub-sub-directories

Comment: @emotionull Not sure what HTTP or HTTPS has to do with the request, unless they end up in 2 different places or you have redirect rules that affect SSL vs non-SSL

Comment: I am using `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\.]*)$ /subdirectory/$1 [L]` . How to handle slashes(/) in this regex? I tried with escaping and not-escaping it but gave Error 500 in both case

Comment: Ok. Just tried and concluded that I have to handle sub-sub-directories separately